# Filter data in JavaScript with more than one filter value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a web application that displays products and has two checkboxes as filters. "Show Available Products" and "Show Products With Photos".

When you click on either one of them separately, they filter properly on their own. If you select both checkboxes at once, they do not work together.

What I have so far for the filter code below:

```
const getFilteredSearchResults = (filters: Types.searchFilters, famData) => {
  //filter based on all search filters
  let filteredResults = _.filter(famData, function (p) {
    //apply filters
    if (
      typeof p["serial-number"] === "undefined" ||
      (filters.rentalFleetAvailability && p["availability"] === "No") ||
      (filters.rentalFleetWithImages &&
        (p["photos"] === undefined || !p["photos"].length))
    ) {
      return false; //don't include in listings
    } else if (
      filters.rentalFleetAvailability &&
      p["availability"] === "Yes" &&
      filters.rentalFleetWithImages &&
      p["photos"].length
    ) {
      return true; //include in listings
    } else {
      return true; //include in listings
    }
  });
};
```

Full code for above reference [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/toromont-used-equipment-sqxqu?file=/src/pages/listings/functions/getFilteredSearchResults.ts) and code where it's rendered [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/toromont-used-equipment-sqxqu?file=/src/pages/listings/components/CheckboxCertified.tsx).

Comment: In your else add second condition(another if) and only return true if both are met

Comment: @VojinPurić thanks for the suggestion! Just added the second condition with what you mentioned, didn't work. Did I code it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the info I gathered from your edit and comment this is what I think you want

```
const getFilteredSearchResults = (filters: Types.searchFilters, famData) => {
    //filter based on all search filters
    let filteredResults = _.filter(famData, function (p) {
      //apply filters
      if (
        typeof p["serial-number"] === "undefined" ||
        (filters.rentalFleetAvailability && p["availability"] === "No") ||
        (filters.rentalFleetWithImages &&
          (p["photos"] === undefined || !p["photos"].length))
      ) {
          //First condition falied we are definetely not accepting this item no need to check other condition
        return false; //don't include in listings
      } else  {
        //First condition passed we need to check second
        if (filters.rentalFleetAvailability &&
            p["availability"] === "Yes" &&
            filters.rentalFleetWithImages &&
            p["photos"].length){
                //Both conditions are met here we return true
                return true; //include in listings
            }else{
                //second condition not met we do not include this
                return false;
            }
      }
    });
  };
```